# How to convert wanted values from CityGML to GeoJSON using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, geojson

First there is this [CityGML](https://github.com/rio0810/numazu-citygml-files/blob/main/52383622_bldg_6697_op.gml) file 
Then I want to add a note to this [xsl file](https://github.com/rio0810/numazu-citygml-files/blob/main/style.xsl) to get `gen:valu` and generate GeoJson with the following structure.　
`xsltproc style.xsl 53392643_bldg_6697_op2.gml > index.geojson`
How do I rewrite the xsl file?
Sorry if the English is strange because I am translating from Japanese to English. Please let me know if you need any other information.

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "z": 3,
    "buildingID": "22203-bldg-562"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          138.77809852668528,
          34.939526582609396
        ],
        [
          138.77803651940917,
          34.93950339425915
        ],
        [
          138.77805028353634,
          34.93947843686556
        ],
        [
          138.77807589974992,
          34.939488015045036
        ],
        [
          138.77809694303997,
          34.93944985234779
        ],
        [
          138.77809335876165,
          34.939448517348794
        ],
        [
          138.77809785248826,
          34.93944036670756
        ],
        [
          138.7781613285196,
          34.93946410156609
        ],
        [
          138.77814943590874,
          34.93948566512662
        ],
        [
          138.7781259461289,
          34.93947687539607
        ],
        [
          138.77809852668528,
          34.939526582609396
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Please (1) post your code within the question, not in external links and (2) reduce the code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I will come back out with the corrections to the areas you pointed out.

Comment: Resolved here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72726113/how-to-take-specific-values-from-xml-and-convert-them-to-geojson

Comment: @rio0810 Please don't cross post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take specific values from xml and convert them to GeoJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72726113/how-to-take-specific-values-from-xml-and-convert-them-to-geojson)